# Mat-table inside mat-dialog

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I want to create a table inside a dialog box so when user clicks on a link they can see the table in a dialog box.

I created mat-table and dialog box. Only problem is dialog.open() function takes components as a parameter so dialog box shows all of the page again. Is there a way to give it tables id or something so that i can only show specific table in it?

```
constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) { }
  
openDialog() {
  this.dialog.open(UserProfileComponent);
}
```

html
`<a  value="case1" (click)="openDialog()">Click for details</a>`

Comment: Create a component with a table it it then use that component for mat-dialog with data for the table passed in the params

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `ts` thats open the popup:

```
this.dialog.open(DialogOverviewExampleDialog, {
  data: {id: someId}
});
```

In the popup:

```
  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogOverviewExampleDialog>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: DialogData) {
    if(data.id) {
     // do something
    }
  }
```